# Get max value of 3d numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the following 3d numpy is given:

```
myArray = np.array([[[1,1,5],
                    [1,1,1],
                    [1,6,1]],
                    [[2,2,2],
                    [2,3,2],
                    [2,2,2]],
                   [[3,3,1],
                    [7,1,1],
                    [1,3,3]]])
```

One need to calculate the max value of row and return a list of length 3.

I.e. in the above example the expected result is:

```
[7,6,5]
```

Comment: How about reading the docs of `np.max`? I wonder what the `axis=...` option is for?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Since you have not yet researched the algorithm nor attempted to code the problem yourself, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to reduce an axis, then you can use `np.max`

```
myArray = myArray.ravel().reshape(9,3)
np.max(myArray,axis=0)
```

Comment: No you don't 'need' this weird reshaping step. You can do much better: `myArray.max(axis=(0,2))`

Comment: @Julien Thank you, I didn't know `axis` can take more than one args.

Comment: Thank @Julien, I think in reference to the above data, it should be done like this: ```myArray.max(axis=(0,1))```